# Adding a wizard to a blank project: "The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wizard

I've created a custom wizard that generates a windows form through code that lists out some SQL queries for the user.  For almost all of the testing of the form and the wizard itself, adding it to a blank project would bring up the form and I could test the button click events and other general form stuff. Most recently I fleshed out the listbox's event listeners and ever since then I get this error:

[image]

Googling has lead me to a lot of posts about Ruby, which I'm not using. Other suggestions were reboot and re installation, and those proved unsuccessful. I attempted to comment out the listbox events but that did not keep the error from occuring, however, if it helps here are the events in question:

```
//-----------Event fired when a listbox object is double-clicked; populate the listbox with the new databases---------
    public void dataList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //temp string used to hold the name of the clicked object
        string selectedNAME = dataList.SelectedItem.ToString();

        firstSEL.TableVar = selectedNAME;

        foreach (tempDataVar t in dataVars)
        {
            if (t.TableVar == firstSEL.TableVar)
            {
                firstSEL = t;
            }
        }

        string newQ = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + firstSEL.TableVar + "' AND TABLE_SCHEMA= '" + firstSEL.SchemaVar + "'";//order by TABLE_NAME'";

        results = GetDataSet(bldr.ToString(), newQ);

        //listBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow row in results.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            //foreach (object x in row.ItemArray)
            //{
            //  listBox1.Items.Add(x.ToString());
            //}

            for (int x = 0; x < row.ItemArray.Length; x++)
            {
                if (x == 0)
                {
                    colList.Items.Add(row.ItemArray[x]);
                }
            }
        }

        dataList.Enabled = false;
    }
    //-----------------------------Event that fires when the index of the second listbox changes--------------------------
    private void colList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnYes.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noobie mistake fixed by a co-worker! I blindly copied and pasted the following code from a "How to make a wizard tutorial":

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("20184B81-7C38-4E02-A1E3-8D564EEC2D25"),
ProgId("MyNewWizard.Class1")]
```

This code needed to be directly above the MyNewWizard class and I accidentally pasted in my custom TempDataVar class in the white space between these lines and the start of the MyNewWizard class.  If you're receiving a similar error then I'd suggest testing around the order of some of your attributes/classes!